# Authentication problem: can't access proprietary ArcGIS portal

Tags: javascript, arcgis-server, authentication

I am currently developping a MFC application that loads html and javascript code, using the ArcGIS JavaScript API (4.17), to display a map, where I am adding feature and graphic layers. I must as well add that I am not using the ArcGIS Web AppBuilder. All good until now and I want now to upload these data/feature layers on a specific proprietary ArcGIS portal. The authentication pattern I am trying to develop is the named user login workflow.

I tried thus to follow this tutorial and use the code provided by it: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/identity-oauth-basic/index.html
My application is registered on the proprietary ArcGIS account and I have its client/application ID.
As many, I have this "redirect_uri" error displayed when I am launching my application and try to sign in, and even when I am naively double click on the unmodified identity-oauth-basic.html file provided by the aforementioned tutorial. Following that, I got a bit confused with what I can find on the net to solve this problem.

From what I gathered from the net, I understand that I need to specify on the ArcGIS portal the URL of the page users of my app are redirected to after they successfully log in.
But in my case, everything is local and I am basically embedding an HTML file through my application. Thus I don't know what to specify as a "redirect url" in the "Authentication" pane of the registered application on the ArcGIS account.
I tried to add "http://localhost/" and "https://localhost/" as some tutorials and forum posts may specify it, but the problem is still here. I wouldn't actually know what I should type in a web browser to point to my HTML file, except from its absolute path.
I added as well as a "redirect url" the address I am specifying in my OAuthInfo instance. Here as well I am getting confused about the different specified URLs. The proprietary portal URL I am trying to work with has the following format: https://.maps.arcgis.com. But some URLs are specified with the '/arcgis' (redirects to a non-found page in my case) at the end and the aforementioned tutorial is even adding the '/sharing' extension (redirects to a page where I can be redirected to the ArcGIS API reference). What are the conventions here and what should I use in my OAuthInfo instance and on the application authentication settings?

Can someone clarify these different points so I can move forward with this authentication problem?

Comment: The redirect URLs you're adding to your registered app need to match the URL in your browser. So if you're testing/developing with "https://localhost", then use that. Are you an administrator in your Org? If so, goto *Setting* > *Security* and scroll down to *Trusted Servers* AND *Allow Origins* section. Add the matching URL to both sections (https://locahost) and save. I suggest that as it sounds like a possible CORS issue.

Comment: The application loads a html file (that I developed and which is one of the application resources) and execute the code implemented by it. Does it mean so that I am testing/developing with "localhost"? I am an administrator with respect to the machine I am developing the application on but at the level of the server I want to uploade my data on.

Comment: My *localhost* comments were turned into real links which may have confused my question. On your local machine, you're testing your html code by opening a web browser and going to `http://localhost` right? This is the where your authentication is being redirected from. This URL (or the actual URL you're using to test on YOUR machine) is the URL I'm suggesting you add to *arcgis.com* in the *Security* settings.

Comment: Additionally, you say **proprietary** ArcGIS Portal. Do you mean you have Portal installed locally, in YOUR environment. And you are NOT using ArcGIS Online (arcgis.com)?

Comment: - On your local machine, you're testing your html code by opening a web browser and going to http://localhost?
Actually no, my application has a resource folder where from the html/javascript code is located and executed. When I open the html file, including my html and javascript code, with a web browser, I only see the absolute path of the file in the address bar.
- Additionally, you say proprietary ArcGIS Portal.
"private" may be a better adjective. This arcgis portal is managed by another company. I am trying to upload a feature layer I am creating locally on this portal.

Comment: There are a lot of variables in your situation. But most of my suggestions stand: 1) Run you code/webpage through a web server, so you're accessing it like `https://localhost` on your local machine. If you still get the redirect error, have an Administrator for that Portal add `https://localhost` to the *Trusted Servers* and *Origins* section like I previously mentioned.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestion and your help.